# C# -How to deselect wrap in the whole Excel file Using C#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

i have create the `Excel` File But `Wrap Text` Automatically `Excel` Selected but i want to my project run and excel will be open then Wrap Text deselected in `excel` file 
**I am Not Used the RANGE Class without Work in excel..**

i am data all Transfer to `excel` but name filed using but some cases using the long name then row automatically next line generated then i am deselected wrap text then properly view the `excel` data format

i am using the `C# Windows Application` and Excel version `Microsoft-Office-2016`

**My code**

Excel Open Code..

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new 
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Workbook xlWorkBook = 
 ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
```

I am Using the Looping..

```
 foreach (DataColumn column in dtDataTable1.Columns)
            {
                sb.Append("<td style='border: 1px solid black'>" + column.ColumnName + "</td>");
            }
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            ExcelApp.Windows.Application.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = false;
            StringBuilder objSB = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (DataRow row in dtDataTable1.Rows)
            {
                sb.Append("<tr>");

                sb.Append("<td style='width:100px;border: 1px solid black'>" + index.ToString() + "</td>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in dtDataTable1.Columns)
                {
                    sb.Append("<td style='width:100px;border: 1px solid black'>" + row[column.ColumnName].ToString() + "</td>");
                }
                index++;
                sb.Append("</tr>");
            }
```

Data will Export in excel

**Show excel Store file**

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook xlWorkBook1 = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
            xlWorkBook1 = Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\Krupal\\Desktop\\" + Todaysdate + "\\Summury_final " + Convert.ToDateTime(cmbmonth.SelectedItem).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + ".XLS", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet Wt = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook1.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            Excel.Visible = true;
```

Please help me 
Advance Thank You

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your comment around Rang, are you saying you cannot use the Range property? Because if you can something like this will work. xlWorkSheet.Range["A4:A4"].Cells.WrapText = true;

Comment: @RyanThomas     Thanks !! but i am not using particular range i am used the The whole excel

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to set it for the entire worksheet but you could select the entire range using something like this? var lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("a1").End(xlToRight).Column
var lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(65536, lastCol).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("a1", ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Select

Comment: @RyanThomas  without range  i am used the wrap text deselected